# Uncaught Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

I need some help again. I'm setting up a new angular project, however when I add a new module it crashes the project and displayed the errors below:

[image]

How do i fix this kind of error in angular project? I only added this component on the app.module.ts (before adding the CardsModule the project runs smoothly)

```
import {CardsModule} from '@btx-components/cards';
```

Answer (score 0):

install another version of angularfire2 also firebase.
for firebase :5.0.0-rc.9  and 7.24.0  for firebase:

```
$ npm install firebase@7.24.0
$ npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9
```